# How to write $\cos(\frac{\pi x}{36})=\frac{8}{13}$ in the form "$a\;\arccos b$"?

Tags: trigonometry

Here is a question -

> [image]

My working -

$10$ cm water depth corresponds to $\displaystyle 16\;\sec(\frac{\pi x}{36})-32=-6$
$\displaystyle\Rightarrow\; \sec(\frac{\pi x}{36})=\frac{13}{8}$

$\displaystyle\therefore\; \cos(\frac{\pi x}{36})=\frac{8}{13}$

This is how far I could get. How would you write this in the form "$a\;\arccos b$"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean to write the width as $2|x|=a\arccos b$? If so, try $a=\frac{72}{\pi},\,b=\frac{8}{13}$.

Comment: Could you also explain why it is $2|x|$?

Comment: @Justin The width is between $x$ and $-x$, because of the symmetry around the $y$-axis due to the cosine function being even.